# Check for something in database within a echo tag

Tags: php, sql, if-statement

I'm using a while loop to echo out the users that are in the database in a table. Now, I want to check if the column "loggedin" is set to 1 (and if so, I want to put something with online after the name). This is my code:

```
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
</tr>
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultUsers))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><a class='btn btn-default' href='member.php?user=" . $row['id'] . "'>Bekijk</a> <a class='btn btn-default' href='member.php?user=" . $row['id'] . "&sendrequest=1s'>Stuur vriendschapsverzoek</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

Now, I want to add some sort of code that checks if the user is online. Like this:

```
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "" . if($row['loggedin'] === 1) {"<p>Online</p>"} . "</td>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most preferred and better way to write html as it is and append `PHP` code with html like:

```
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
</tr>
<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultUsers)) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>;
        <td><?php echo $row['date']; ?></td>;
        <td>
            <a class='btn btn-default' href='member.php?user=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'>Bekijk</a> <a class='btn btn-default' href='member.php?user=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>&sendrequest=1s'>Stuur vriendschapsverzoek</a>
            <?php if ($row['loggedin'] === 1) { ?>
                <p>Online</p>
            <?php } ?>
        </td>
    </tr>;
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much. From now on, I'll use this method (way easier...)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ternary operator:

```
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . " " . ($row['loggedin'] === 1 ? "<p>Online</p>" : "") . "</td>";
```

Comment: Beat me to it to by a second! +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ternary operators. Try this:

```
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "" . (!empty($row['loggedin']) && $row['loggedin'] === 1) ? '<p>Online</p>' : '' . "</td>";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This has already been answered and `empty()` is not relevant there.

Answer (score 0):

ternary need to use ternary operator.

```
echo "<td>" . $row['name'];
echo $row['loggedin'] === 1 ? '<p>Online</p>' : '';
echo "</td>";
```

For one line code

```
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "" . ($row['loggedin'] === 1 ? "<p>Online</p>" : '' ) . "</td>";
```

It is always good to look at if it is set (isset($row['whatevercolumn']))
Do not use empty() check, as a default if it is empty it will throw false. So not necessary to put extra function to consume your resource.

Comment: `isset()` is unnecessary too, as long as the field is selected in the query.